# NGINX PROXY 0000 1204 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000 8000

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, freebsd

After last update of nginx all my pages are getting:

```
    0000 1204 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000 8000
    0400 0000 0000 0500 ffff ff00 0004 0800
    0000 0000 7fff 0000 0000 0807 0000 0000
    0000 0000 0000 0000 01
```

There is a FreeBSD/10.2-RELEASE-p17 box with jails.

1. 10.10.10.1:80 : Apache/2.4.20 - as a internal network only  - generic virtual hosts
2. XX.XX.XX.XX:80 : nginx/1.10.0 as proxy and load balancer to Apache24 - that is public facing

Test from internal network works (apache) on all files:

```
curl -I --header 'Host: myserver.com' http://10.10.10.1:80/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 May 2016 11:23:08 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: _icl_current_language=en; expires=Sat, 21-May-2016 11:23:08 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/
Set-Cookie: _icl_current_language=en; expires=Sat, 21-May-2016 11:23:08 GMT;     Max-Age=86400; path=/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Test from internal or external network (nginx) fails on all files:

```
curl -I --header 'Host: myserver.com' http://XX.XX.XX.XX:80/
▒▒
```

It is happening with all configs; no SSL involved for this server.

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name myserver.com
        expires off;
    location / {
        proxy_no_cache   1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.1:80/;
        }
    }
```

Initially I thought it might be connected with http/2 but I am not using it on this hosts configuration. Nginx has multiple hosts and some have a http/2 connection to other nginx http/2 hosts - this works fine. There is invalid SSL installed for the other hosts proxy on nginx - but it works.

Here is NGINX -v

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.0
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: 
--prefix=/usr/local/etc/nginx 
--with-cc-opt='-I /usr/local/include' 
--with-ld-opt='-L /usr/local/lib' 
--conf-path=/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx 
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx-error.log 
--user=www 
--group=www 
--modules-path=/usr/local/libexec/nginx 
--with-ipv6 
--with-google_perftools_module 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/client_body_temp 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi_temp 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/scgi_temp 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/uwsgi_temp 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx-access.log 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/nginx_accept_language_module-2f69842 
--with-http_addition_module 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/nginx-auth-ldap-8517bb0 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/ngx_http_auth_pam_module-1.2 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/ngx_cache_purge-2.3 
--add-dynamic-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/headers-more-nginx-module-f5559ec 
--with-http_dav_module 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/nginx-http-footer-filter-1.2.2 
--with-http_geoip_module=dynamic 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/nginx-notice-3c95966 
--with-http_perl_module=dynamic 
--with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_slice_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_xslt_module=dynamic 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/ngx_devel_kit-0.2.19 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/memc-nginx-module-0.16 
--with-pcre 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/xss-nginx-module-0.04 
--with-http_v2_module 
--with-stream=dynamic 
--with-stream_ssl_module 
--with-threads 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--add-module=/wrkdirs/usr/ports/www/nginx/work/iconv-nginx-module-0.10
```

This happen only to Apache servers that are behind. The same configuration was working for last 6 years; this happened after the nginx upgrade.

Any idea what might be happening? Bug?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this additional data? In the begging of the frame? In one of the headers? In the HTML body? Is it for every file downloaded from Apache or only some files? Can you debug the network activity with Firefox or Chrome developer tools and check what you see in the raw mode?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you access Apache directly via `http://10.10.10.1:80/`, or does it only appear when proxying via Nginx?

Comment: It is not additional data - it is only data i get. Internal query to apache - works fine (curl)- proper files and headers. Nginx answer has no headers or html only this numbers. It is affecting all files and servers that have apache in a backend, when backend is nginx it works fine. nginx <=> apache fails. 
Raw is only this numbers or wired characters, but always the same.

Comment: For me this error happened when I had a `server` section enabled in nginx that had `http2` enabled but not `ssl`. [Related link](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/33118)

Answer (score 0):

The hexdump contains HTTP/2 SETTINGS and WINDOW_UPDATE data. Have a look with `nghttp -n -vvv '<host>' --hexdump`. The last bits `0000 0807 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 01` express an error, see [rfc7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-7). Not sure, but looks like a GOAWAY frame with an error code at the end.

Your curl speaks http/1.1 to an nginx http/2 port - without the proper upgrade language to receive http2, probably not compiled against nghttp2. Nginx on its part doesn't do http/1.1 yet on a http/2 enabled port (see [#816](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/816)) in nginx bugtrac). So your version of curl and version of nginx can't speak to each other. You can search if you accidentially listen on port 80 with http2 enabled or proxy http2 to port 80 in one of your included server {} blocks.